# split sklearn's IncrementalPCA (ipca.transform) input, based on features instead of samples

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I have a huge input for IncrementalPCA on number of features:  (22, 258186260)
I wonder if its okay to split sklearn's IncrementalPCA (ipca.transform) input based on features instead of samples. Would the result still be correct.

```
               ipca = IncrementalPCA(n_components=2)
               for batch in np.split( input, 10,axis=1):
                     
                     output=ipca.transform(batch)
```

Comment: It would find different principal components, but those principal components might still be useful for your purpose, depending on what it is.

Comment: So it looks from your answer it is not possible.